# What is the equivalent to motd.tail in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, server, login

`motd.tail` is deprecated according to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/manpages/+bug/785901):

```
motd(5) says: "The contents of this file are regenerated upon every system
boot based on the contents of /etc/motd.tail." This is not true anymore, as
Ubuntu uses the update-motd framework. Any reference to motd.tail should be
replaced with a reference to the update-motd framework or update-motd(5).
The manpage for motd.tail should be removed.
```

I'm using it to identify my servers when I log in and make sure I'm on the right machine, so I don't need anything dynamic, just a simple message.

What is the equivalent to `motd.tail` (appending a small message to the end of the MOTD) that works with Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question directly, just edit `/etc/update-motd.d/99-footer`.

The `/etc/update-motd.d/` is a fairly standard config-dump that is ordered by filename. `99-footer` is the last thing in there so that gets bolted on last. In Natty by default this just checks to see if there's a file called `/etc/motd.tail` and if there is, it appends that to the motd:

```
[ -f /etc/motd.tail ] && cat /etc/motd.tail || true
```

So you do have two choices. You can either add some more logic in there to just `echo` some output (this is a shell script, not a textfile after all) or you can create (or edit if you already have one) `/etc/motd.tail`. Either way is perfectly valid.

Comment: Ok, strangely enough I had to restart the machine. Because it wasn't reading the file. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ubuntu Server Guide, `pam_motd` executes the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` in numerical order.
The output of the scripts is written to /var/run/motd, keeping the numerical order, then concatenated with /etc/motd.tail.

More information can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/pam_motd.html).